# How to make website fullscreen in smartphone?

Tags: html, css

https://sagarj2021.github.io/first-website/

This is my website but it only open fullscreen in destop of my laptop. It does not open in fullscreen in smartphones destop as well as in normal search. (Actully in smartphone right side is 50% of white blank color). I dont know how to fix this issue..

I have given my code also,
so please can you help mi ?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-left: 8%;
  padding-right: 8%;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
  color: red;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: red;
  transition: .4s;
}

.btn {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: transform .4s;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 8%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 20px 0px 20px;
  font-size: 75px;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

h4 {
  color: #fcfc;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.newslatter form {
  width: 380px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.newslatter form input:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 14px 130px 14px 15px;
  border: 2px solid #f9004d;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.newslatter form input:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #f9004d;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000, 0px 0px 15px #858585;
  top: 6px;
  right: 6px;
}

.about {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px 0px;
  background-color: #191919;
}

.about img {
  height: auto;
  width: 430px;
}

.about-text {
  width: 550px;
}

.main {
  width: 1130px;
  max-width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.about-text h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 75px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.about-text h5 {
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.about-text p {
  color: #fcfc;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

button {
  background-color: #f9004d;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 13px 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: .4s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #f9004d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.service {
  background: #101010;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px 0px;
}

.title h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 75px;
  width: 1130px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.card {
  height: 365px;
  width: 335px;
  padding: 20px 35px;
  background: #191919;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.card i {
  font-size: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0px;
  color: #f9004d;
}

h5 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 23px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.pra p {
  color: #fcfc;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.card .button {
  background-color: #f9004d;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 9px 22px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: .4s;
}

.card .button:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #f9004d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-me {
  width: 100%;
  height: 290px;
  background: #191919;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.contact-me p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.contact-me .button-two {
  background-color: #f9004d;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 13px 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: .4s;
}

.contact-me .button-two:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #f9004d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #101010;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

footer p:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

footer p:nth-child(2) {
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.social {
  display: flex;
}

.social a {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #f9004d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 22px 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.social a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  transition: .3s;
}

.end {
  position: absolute;
  color: #f9004d;
  bottom: 35px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!--Sagar personal website-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="personalprofile.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/34d51c031e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Personal website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hero">
    <nav>
      <h2 class="logo">Portfo<span>lio</span></h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a href="https://www.blogger.com/blog/posts/4753586747609698916?bpli=1&pli=1" class="btn">Blog</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="content">
      <h4>hello, my name is</h4>
      <h1>Sagar<span>Jadhav</span></h1>
      <h3>I'm a Web Developer.</h3>
      <div class="newslatter">
        <form action="">
          <input type="email" name="email" id="mail" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Let start">
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!---About section start-->

  <section class="about">
    <div class="main">
      <img src="#" alt="">
      <div class="about-text">
        <h2>About Me</h2>
        <h5>Developer & Designer</h5>
        <p>
          I am a front-end web developer. I can provide clean code and pixel perfect design. I also make the website more & more interactive with web animations. I can provide clean code and pixel perfect design. I also make the website more & more interactive
          with web animations. A responsive design makes your website accessible to all users, regardless of their devices.
        </p>

        <button type="button">Let's Talk</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!--Service section start-->

  <div class="service">
    <div class="title">
      <h2>Our Services</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        <h5>Web Development</h5>
        <div class="pra">
          <p>Every website should be built with two primary goals: Firstly, it needs to work across all devices. Secondly, it needs to be fast as possible. </p>

          <p style="text-align: center;">
            <a class="button" href="#">Read More</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-user"></i>
        <h5>Web Development</h5>
        <div class="pra">
          <p>Every website should be built with two primary goals: Firstly, it needs to work across all devices. Secondly, it needs to be fast as possible. </p>

          <p style="text-align: center;">
            <a class="button" href="#">Read More</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-bell"></i>
        <h5>Web Development</h5>
        <div class="pra">
          <p>Every website should be built with two primary goals: Firstly, it needs to work across all devices. Secondly, it needs to be fast as possible. </p>

          <p style="text-align: center;">
            <a class="button" href="#">Read More</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Contact Me-->
  <div class="contact-me">
    <p>For any help.</p>
    <a class="button-two" href="#">Contact Me</a>
  </div>

  <!--Footer start-->
  <footer>
    <p>Sagar Jadhav</p>
    <p>For coding and syber security related update follow my blog chennal - please click on the link below to follow me:
    </p>
    <div class="social">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i></a>
    </div>
    <p class="end">CopyRight By Sagar Jadhav</p>
  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's because you gave most of them as in fixed px. for example

.title h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 75px;
  width: 1130px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

Also if you are making it mobile responsive try to add media queries as well to make it responsive across every platform.

Comment: Among other things, you have fixed widths up to 1130px in your `main`section which (also)  cause the overflow to the right

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code in your code

```
.title h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 75px;
  width: 130px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```